# How do I get the strong name of an assembly?

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to **'friend'** a dll library that I didn't author.

I can see in the properties that it has a strong name, but how can I find out what the strong name is, so I can use it in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the public key of a strong-named assembly, use the [sn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) tool:

```
sn -Tp assembly.dll
```

This will show you the public key that you need to put in the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. If you open a Visual Studio command prompt, the sn.exe tool will already be in the path.

**However**, I would question what you are trying to actually achieve. If you have a compiled assembly that you did not write, adding the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to your code will let it access the internals of your code, but it wouldn't have compiled without already having friend access. If you are trying to access the internals of the other assembly, then the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute *will need adding to the other assembly* - something which you cannot do without recompiling it..

Comment: The assembly i'm trying to friend is using reflection against my code, and it breaks when the reflection code discovers that its running against an internal class that it shouldn't access. These errors are at run time not compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify fully qualified name and public key token in AssemblyInfo.cs file of assembly you "need a friend":

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FullAssemblyName, PublicKey=....", )]
```

If you have Reflector.NET or ildasm in hand you can use it to see this information